# using spservices to search a list

Tags: jquery, sharepoint

I am trying to search a sharepoint list called mollyList. It has column name Food, Calories, weight... ect. I modified this sample code below, but I keep getting an error:
POST /_vti_bin/Lists.asmx 500 (Internal Server Error)

And I have no idea what is the issue? Can someone check out my code?

```js
<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false -->
```

```html
<body>
  <table><tbody><tr><td align="right">Calories</td>
<td align="left"><input id="firstName" type="text"/></td></tr>
<tr><td align="right">weight:</td>
<td align="left"><input id="wt" type="text"/></td></tr>
<tr><td align="right">weight:</td>
<td align="left"><input id="wt2" type="text"/></td></tr></tbody></table>
<p><input id="sb" type="button" value="Search"/> </p>
<ul id="searchResults"></ul>  

</body>
```

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#sb").click(function(){
    alert("this");
$("#searchResults").empty();
var query = "";
var key = "";

//Build Query from input
if($("#firstname").val()){
key = $("#firstname").val();
query = "<Query><Where><Or><Contains><FieldRef Name='Food'/><Value Type='Text'>"+ key +"</Value></Contains><Contains><FieldRef Name='calories'/><Value Type='Text'>"+ key +"</Value></Contains></Or></Where></Query>";
}

// Pass query to Function
if(query)
sendQuery(query);
else
$("#searchResults").append("Please enter atleast one value");

//If no results found
if (!$("#searchResults").html())
{
$("#searchResults").append("No Results Found");
}

});
});

function sendQuery(spQuery)
{
var thisSite = $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentSite();
//function to get all the lists
$().SPServices({
operation: "GetListItems",
async:false,
webURL: $(this).attr("/Lists/mollyList/AllItems.aspx"),
listName: $(this).attr("mollyList"),
CAMLQuery: spQuery,
CAMLRowLimit: 100,   
completefunc: function(xData, Status) {

}
});
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<table><tbody><tr><td align="right">Look Up:</td>
<td align="left"><input id="firstname" type="text"/></td></tr>
</tbody></table>
<p><input id="sb" type="button" value="Search"/> </p>
<ul id="searchResults"></ul>
Generate SPQuery and pass to the function: 



</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `sendQuery()` function looks wrong to me, specifically these two lines:

```
webURL: $(this).attr("/Lists/mollyList/AllItems.aspx"),
listName: $(this).attr("mollyList"),
```

It's not clear what `listName: $(this).attr("mollyList"),` is achieving for you. If you already know that the list name is "mollyList" then the correct code should be `listName: "mollyList",`

If you're trying to access a list on a different site, then `webURL` should be the URL of the site on which the list resides, presumably in the following syntax: `webUrl: "http://server.com/site/web",`

The [documentation](http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=GetListItems&referringTitle=Lists) for the GetListItems operation suggests that `listName` should be the display name of your list, while `webURL` is optional if you're executing the code on the site where the list resides.

Also note that if you're working with SharePoint 2010 or above, you also have the built-in JavaScript object model that you can work with. You can find Microsoft's documentation on the JavaScript client object model here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh185015(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: I modified the code a bit based off of https://spbreed.wordpress.com/2013/05/02/contact-search-using-spservices/#comment-1008      At this point, just trying to get anything to returned. I removed what yiou mentioned above and it still didn work. I found a tutorial or some code where I no longer get the 500 error, but I dont think It can find the list.